# Testing GWTP with Mockito

Tags: java, gwt, guice, mockito, gwt-platform

I am using Mockito to test my GWTP project and I got some error:

```
    com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest was bound.
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider<javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest>
    for parameter 0 at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.guice.request.DefaultRequestProvider.<init>(DefaultRequestProvider.java:35)
  at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.guice.DispatchModule.configure(DispatchModule.java:135)
```

Below is the code for unit test:

```
@Mock
private TestActionHandler mockTestActionHandler;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServerModule(), new MockHandlerModule() {

        @Override
        protected void configureMockHandlers() {
                bindMockActionHandler(TestActionHandler.class, 
                        mockTestActionHandler);
            }
        }); 
}
```

Here is the code for TestActionHandler:

```
public class TestActionHandler implements ActionHandler<TestAction, TestResult> {

    private final Provider<HttpServletRequest> provider;

    @Inject
    public RetrieveEventsUsingCategoryIdActionHandler(
            final Provider<HttpServletRequest> provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public TestResult execute(TestAction action, ExecutionContext context) {
        //handle action
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me fix this? Thaks a lot!

Comment: how do your ServerModule and MockHandlerModule class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to dinde's [post in GWTP group](http://groups.google.com/group/gwt-platform/browse_thread/thread/15769eea6f8d5609/0b7fe1f0e5b6b51c?show_docid=0b7fe1f0e5b6b51c), I have resolved this problem.

It seems that the test is complaining about missing `Provider` for `HttpServletRequest`, so in the `setUp` of the test, I add a provider fo the `HttpServletRequest` and the problem is solved. Here's the working code:

```
@Mock
private TestActionHandler mockTestActionHandler;
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServerModule(), new MockHandlerModule() {

        @Override
        protected void configureMockHandlers() {
                bindMockActionHandler(TestActionHandler.class, 
                        mockTestActionHandler);
            }
        });

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Provides 
        public HttpServletRequest createServletRequest() { 
            return servletRequest; 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The field annotated both with @Bind and @Mock inside a test class

```
@Bind
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

works for me using mycila-testing-guice2 plugin.